# Configuring laravel apache2 to load public fails

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

I would like to configure laravel to whenever a user accesses `domain/api` he actually accesses the public folder

I have tried the following

1.Created a file laravel.conf with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName ipaddress/api

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api/public

  <Directory /var/www/html/api>
     AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf //disabled defaul loading
sudo a2ensite laravel.conf
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But now the above fails

But on the virtualHost configuration when i make `servername to ipaddress` without api whenever i visit the ip address it reads api/public but i would like it to read api/public whenever a user visits

```
ipaddress/api.
```

What else do i need to add?

I was following
[This tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Apache configurations, so I'm not sure what's different between what you have and what the tutorial used.

However, I have a similar setup for my websites, however mine looks a little different:

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/website/public

 <Directory /var/www/website/public>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
  </Directory>
```

Put into context of your configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName ipaddress/api

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api/public

  <Directory /var/www/html/api/public>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Perhaps give that a try and see if that helps.